# Python script, replace item at index with item at index

Tags: python, list, indexing, replace

I'm trying to create a python script.

I have situation in which i have two lists.

If the item from the list1

==[] (empty list)
OR
=="Pxxx-xx"

then it must be replaced with the item from the second list at the same index.

so:

```
list1 =["P324-12","P321-01","Pxxx-xx",[],"P134-23"]

list2 =["A00","A01","A02","A03","A04"]
```

then output should be:

```
out=["P324-12","P321-01","A02","A03","P134-23"]
```

now i got this to work:

```
list1 = IN[0]
replacement = IN[1]
out = []

for itm in list1:
    if itm == [] or itm == "Pxxx-xx":
        out.append(replacement)
    else:
        out.append(itm)
#Assign your output to the OUT variable.
OUT = out
```

but this only replaces it with a single item, not an item from a replacement list.

now i tried:

```
list1 = IN[0]
list2 = IN[1]
out = []

for idx, itm in enumerate(list1):
    if itm == [] or itm == "Pxxx-xx":
        out.append(list2[idx])
    else:
        out.append(itm)
#Assign your output to the OUT variable.
OUT = out
```

but i get a warning: "IronPythonEvaluator.EvaluateIronPythonScript operation failed.
unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Comment: Your second attempt looks fine; I can't reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of appending in `new list`, initialize the `new list` with `list1` and replace the value in `new list` at specific index

```
list1 =["P324-12","P321-01","Pxxx-xx",[],"P134-23"]
list2 =["A00","A01","A02","A03","A04"]
out = list1
for i, itm in enumerate(out):
    if out[i] == [] or out[i] == "Pxxx-xx":
        out[i]=list2[i]
```

Comment: Thank you, this totally works! And it makes so much sense now that i see it, this is a way simpler way of doing things

Answer (score -1):

I tried the folowing and it seems to work :

```
list1 =["P324-12","P321-01","Pxxx-xx",[],"P134-23"]
list2 =["A00","A01","A02","A03","A04"]
out = []

for idx, itm in enumerate(list1):
    if itm == [] or itm == "Pxxx-xx":
        out.append(list2[idx])
    else:
        out.append(itm)
#Assign your output to the OUT variable.
print(out)
```

What's the use of that part:

```
list1 = IN[0]
list2 = IN[1]
```

Comment: If you can't actually answer the question, please leave a comment instead.

Comment: this is a bit of script that is part of a dynamo script for Autodesk Revit, these rules are just there to get the inputs.
[image example](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/business6/uploads/dynamobim/original/3X/a/b/ab2a53ae8fd4db2f3ada0894cf2f8e1d63005c34.png)

Comment: Even if the accepted answer is more concise, the second version of the script should still work. Maybe some extra spaces were hiding somewhere